# Aptana: disable code assist on php else keyword

Tags: aptana, content-assist

Maybe someone knows how to disable content assist only on 'else' keyword when working with PHP source editor in Aptana?

As I really, really hate it with this keyword, because after newest release it's really messing with my workflow as after entering 'else' and pressing enter it replaces it with:

```
else {
  [cursor stays here]
}
```

and sometimes it decides to get rid of indents completely.

Mind you I don't want to disable content assist completely, I just want to disable it for 'else' keyword.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by content assist? Are you selecting the element from a content assist popup? Does the item you are selecting have an icon that looks like a small torn page?

Comment: the code assist (in aptana it's called content assist). Code assist automatically select first element in in popup and it's not possible to disable enter (as I found after additional research) it just inserts the first suggestion. Looks like I will have to suck it up for the time being.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Commands > PHP > Edit this bundle
2. Open snippets/snippets.rb in the new php project it just created
3. Delete the two snippets for else around line 85. Save the file

Problem should be gone.